# Searching for detailed shapefiles in Vietnam: Tam Ky and Quy Nhon cities

Tags: data, vietnam

I'm currently interning with UN-Habitat Vietnam in Hanoi, and am helping them produce some basic maps for community development strategies in the coastal cities of Tam Ky and Quy Nhon. This is my first time working in GIS internationally, and I'm realizing quite quickly the differences between here and North America in terms of reliable data acquisition. I'm having a really hard time tracking down shapefiles for the study areas, and am hoping someone with experience doing GIS work in Vietnam could help out with some pointers.

One thing I should mention, is that I have been provided fairly detailed DWG files for both cities. I personally don't have any experience converting CAD into GIS, but I have begun to poke around in AutoCAD to see what I can come up with. However, the file layers are not organized in any way I can comprehend, and many of the polylines are disconnected, and therefore don't translate well to GIS.

Does anyone know where to look for shapefiles in Vietnam?

Comment: You may want to look at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

[DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) has quite a comprehensive list of detailed shapefiles which might be useful. You can select *Vietnam* from the list of countries (I chose *Administrative areas* for the following image):

[image: Vietnam]

Note that the attribute table in my QGIS version hasn't been encoded correctly to Vietnamese, therefore some characters in the names might be incorrect.

**Tam Kỳ:**

[image: Tam Kỳ]

**Qui Nhơn:**

[image: Qui Nhơn]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Joseph! I guess I should have specified what exactly I'm looking for. I actually came across the DIVA-GIS shapefiles the other day, but unfortunately they are lacking some of the finer details I was hoping to find, i.e., road network, waterways, and smaller, block level data. I really appreciate the help, though, and hopefully I can track something down.

Comment: @DavidFiske - Most welcome buddy, hope you find the data you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the map of the world with `AutoCAD` can be found here:

http://www.tonythanh.com/architecture-acad-dwg-block/world-map-cad-block-simple-world-map-autocad-drawing-countries-map/